# How to set ReceiveBufferSize for UDPClient? or Does it make sense to set? C#

Tags: c#, sockets, buffer, udpclient

I am implementing a UDP data transfer thing. I have several questions about UDP buffer.

I am using UDPClient to do the UDP send / receive. and my broadband bandwidth is 150KB/s (bytes/s, not *bps*).

1. I send out a 500B datagram out to 27 hosts
2. 27 hosts send back 10KB datagram back if they receive.
3. So, I should receive 27 responses, right? however, I only get averagely 8 - 12 instead.
4. I then tried to reduce the size of the response down to 500B, yes, I receive all.

A thought of mine is that if all 27 hosts send back 10KB response at almost same time, the incoming traffic will be 270KB/s (likely), that exceeds my incoming bandwidth so loss happens. Am I right?

But I think even if the incoming traffic exceeds the bandwidth, is the Windows supposed to put the datagram in the buffer and wait for receive?

I then suspect that maybe the ReceiveBufferSize of my UdpClient is too small? by default, it is 8092B??

I don't know whether I am all right at these points. Please give me some help.

Comment: 500GB datagram? What could you possibly be sending, your harddrive?

Answer (score 0):

The UDP protocol does not guaratnee delivery, you should switch to TCP if you need to guaratnee packet delivery.

UDP is better suited to apps where loosing a packet is better than waiting for a packet to find its way to you. i.e. streaming media or somehting similar.

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) for more.