# Is it possible to set UdpClient ReceiveBufferSize property in c#?

Tags: c#, udp, overflow, udpclient

I want to change udpclient receivebuffersize in order to prevent buffer overflow when receiving udp packets. is it possible to change it in c#. The actual property is UdpClient.Client.ReceiveBufferSize. Do i have to use other method?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you make sure to [set `ReceiveBufferSize` directly after creating the `UdpClient`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9680672/709537), before doing anything with it?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to doing the following:

```
  UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
  client.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 4096;
```

Comment: I think i did mention that i am aware of UdpClient.Client.ReceiveBufferSize. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivebuffersize.aspx, ReceiveBufferSize is used only for tcpclient. I did test in my udpclient but sees no difference. actually, i veeeery sure it doesnt work for udp. thats why i asked here.

Comment: Others have gotten this to work, check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408212/how-can-i-set-the-buffer-size-for-the-underneath-socket-udp-c

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this helps, but it looks like `UdpClient` allows you to provide your own `Socket`. Internally, `UdpClient` creates the `Socket` with this statement:

```
new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
```

In the `Connect()`, it checks whether `Client` has already been set and, if so, uses that `Socket` to connect to.